# How to Separate Dialogs in Triggered Actions from Prompts (Microsoft Botbuilder SDK)

Tags: node.js, botframework

### Note

I am using Microsoft Botbuilder SDK in `node.js` using ES6 babel.

### The Problem

I have a dialog, '/MainMenu', that prompts the user for a free-response reply in order to dive into another, more relevant dialog. I also, however, want the user to be able to trigger an action that is completely irrelevant to subject matter (i.e. a dialog asking the bot, "how are you?"), returning back to the original MainMenu dialog **just as they left off.** I understand that in the documentation for the SDK, onSelectAction can be used to put the triggered dialog on top of the stack rather than replacing the entire stack, but once the '/HowAreYou' dialog ends, the bot also thinks that response was for the initial MainMenu prompt, replying with "I didn't understand. Please try again," like so:

[image: Bot dialog screenshot]

### Code

```
// I am using the builder.Library routing standard, and have confirmed that     
// this gets triggered as expected. this dialog exists in a different file
lib.dialog('/HowAreYou', [
    (session, args, next) => {
        session.send('I\'m doing well. Thanks for asking!');
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'How are you doing today?');
    }, (session, results) => {
        session.endDialog('Good to hear that!');
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: /^how are you?$/i,
    onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
        // Add the help dialog to the top of the dialog stack (override the    
        // default behavior of replacing the stack)
        session.beginDialog(args.action, args);
    }
});

bot.dialog('mainMenu', [
    (session, args, next) => {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi there! What can I do for you today?');
    },
    (session, results) => {
        session.endConversation('Goodbye!');
    }
]).beginDialogAction('weatherAction', '/Weather', {
    matches: /^weather$/i,
}).beginDialogAction('sportsAction', '/Sports', {
    matches: /^sports$/i,
}).beginDialogAction('cookingAction', '/Cooking', {
    matches: /^cooking$/i,
});
```

### Desired Behavior

Although the current result is very close to the desired behavior, I ideally want the bot to reply with the same MainMenu prompt it began with, **without saying it didn't understand** after the HowAreYou dialog finishes.

### The Question

**Is this possible? If so, how? If not, what are alternatives?**

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Hello, how do you trigger the dialog to start? I am trying to match the intent, but can't get the dialog to start...

Answer (score 0):

There is an explain on GitHub at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2421, with what we can realize that the `Prompts` are built-in dialog which will **handle the input validation**.

As you first step in the Prompts dialog in `mainMenu`, and then you trigger the `HowAreYou` dialog when the first Prompts dialog is waiting for the input text.
Then the `HowAreYou` end as `session.endDialog('Good to hear that!');` without an result for the first Prompts dialog in `mainMenu`, which is failed in the validation.

the root cause should be equivalent to input an empty text for `builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi there! What can I do for you today?');`.

### update

Found the [`promptAfterAction`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L854) property of `IPromptOptions` for prompt dialog, and i think about this issue. I think this should be by design.

As the sentence `I don't understand...` is a default text for property `retryPrompt`. So when you end the `HowAreYou` dialog and back the to `mainPage` dialog stack. The prompt dialog will restart and send the `retryPrompt` to user, which raises your issue.

For the accessibility, you can try to use:

```
builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi there! What can I do for you today?', {
            retryPrompt: 'Hi there! What can I do for you today?'
        });
```

Comment: Hm... this seems to not work as expected. Even if I endDialogWithResult(results), I get the same error (I also noticed that the 2nd waterfall step of the MainMenu dialog never executes). I see in the console that the 2nd step of /HowAreYou successfully calls endDialogWithResult, but all that it logs is `...BotBuilder:prompt-text - Session.send() ...BotBuilder:prompt-text - Session.sendBatch() sending 1 message(s)` at the end. What does the state look like after endDialogWithResult? Or, what should my `results` object be? I would think it'd relate to the beginDialogActions MainMenu expects.

Comment: You need to remove the `session.beginDialog(args.action, args);` in `onSelectAction` function. And the `results` is an instance of `IDialogResult`, specifically `results.response` is your text input for prompts dialog.

Comment: but if I remove `beginDialog`, wouldn't that mean the triggerAction replaces the entire stack, and not return to the MainMenu dialog after the HowAreYou dialog finishes?

Comment: no, it will back to your last dialog. You can try the behaviour.

Comment: I have tried this, and unfortunately the dialog does not go back to re-initiate the MainMenu dialog again. I have tried both removing just the `session.beginDialog` in `onSelectAction`, and removing `onSelectAction` completely, but both have the same result of just sending the message 'Good to hear that!' and nothing afterwards. this makes sense to me since triggerAction replaces the stack. is there something else you are doing that is allowing a re-prompt of the parent dialog? I am also using the LuisAPI. could that explain why this is not working for me? thanks again for your follow-ups.

Comment: Update my answer, and by the way, what's your `botbuilder` version?

Comment: Thank you for the update to your answer. I'll give it a try. My botbuilder version is the latest release: 3.14.0

Comment: I apologize to seemingly keep bringing up the same point, but your first code example demonstrates what I raised up before: the 2nd waterfall step of the MainMenu dialog (in your case, `session.endConversation('Goodbye!');` never runs, which is the desired behavior after the user types "fine" and the bot responds with "Good to hear that." was that behavior simply not part of the screenshot, or is it accurate to say that was not part of the behavior you were able to emulate?

Comment: I apologize for the mistake, and I dig into the source code, find that the issue should be by design. Please see the update for details. Thanks for your  patience.